# Why does the RecyclerView item only change background color after clicking on it twice?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-cardview, android-viewholder

I have been exploring Recyclerview and Cardview and I stumbled across this one problem in which I don't know how to handle it. My recyclerview works fine but when I make the recyclerview's item background change color on click, it behaves weirdly.

Ok so, the recyclerview loads normally however when I first click on an item, the item background color flickers its new color but then stays in its default color. When I click on any item for the second time, only then the recyclerview's item change its background coloras it supposed to along with the rest of the item clicked.

From the `Log.d` that I've added to my code, I found that what differ first click with the second(and the rest) click is the public `PremiseAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)` in the class `PremiseAdapter`. I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47378085/recyclerview-changing-selected-item-icon-needs-two-clicks-to-work) similar my problem but I don't think my code works that way.

The logs are as below.

1. Loads the recyclerview and its Cardview item

```
.... D/rcvTest: PremiseAdapter.PremiseAdapter
.... D/rcvTest: PremiseAdapter.getItemCount
.... D/rcvTest: PremiseAdapter.getItemCount
.... D/rcvTest: ---------------------> PremiseAdapter.ViewHolder.onCreateViewHolder
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].ViewHolder.TOP
.... D/rcvTest: PremiseAdapter.onBindViewHolder
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].bindTo.TOP: FroyYo Mart
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].bindTo.BOTTOM FroyYo Mart
.... D/rcvTest: PremiseAdapter.onBindViewHolder.get(position)
.... D/rcvTest: PremiseAdapter.getItemCount
.... D/rcvTest: ---------------------> PremiseAdapter.ViewHolder.onCreateViewHolder
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].ViewHolder.TOP
.... D/rcvTest: PremiseAdapter.onBindViewHolder
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].bindTo.TOP: Ice Cream Store
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].bindTo.BOTTOM Ice Cream Store
.... D/rcvTest: PremiseAdapter.onBindViewHolder.get(position)
```

2. First click on the item

```
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].ViewHolder.listener: null
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition(): 1
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].ViewHolder.position: 1
.... D/rcvTest: getLayoutPosition(): 1
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].ViewHolder.position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
.... D/rcvTest: PremiseAdapter.getItemCount
.... D/rcvTest: PremiseAdapter.getItemCount
.... D/rcvTest: ---------------------> PremiseAdapter.ViewHolder.onCreateViewHolder
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].ViewHolder.TOP
.... D/rcvTest: PremiseAdapter.onBindViewHolder
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].bindTo.TOP: Ice Cream Store
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].bindTo.BOTTOM Ice Cream Store
.... D/rcvTest: PremiseAdapter.onBindViewHolder.get(position)
```

3. Second(and the rest) click on the item

```
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].ViewHolder.listener: null
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition(): 0
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].ViewHolder.position: 0
.... D/rcvTest: getLayoutPosition(): 0
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].ViewHolder.position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
.... D/rcvTest: PremiseAdapter.getItemCount
.... D/rcvTest: PremiseAdapter.getItemCount
.... D/rcvTest: PremiseAdapter.onBindViewHolder
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].bindTo.TOP: FroyYo Mart
.... D/rcvTest: [ViewHolder].bindTo.BOTTOM FroyYo Mart
.... D/rcvTest: PremiseAdapter.onBindViewHolder.get(position)
.... D/rcvTest: PremiseAdapter.getItemCount
```

And this is my `PremiseAdapter.java` file which contains my `PremiseAdapter` class and `ViewHolder`class.

```
public class PremiseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PremiseAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Premise> mPremiseData;
    private Context context;
    private int selected_position = -1;
    OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        onItemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public PremiseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Premise> mPremiseData) {
        Log.d("rcvTest", "PremiseAdapter.PremiseAdapter");
        this.mPremiseData = mPremiseData;
        this.context = context;
    }

    //Required method for creating the viewholder objects.
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PremiseAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d("rcvTest", "---------------------> PremiseAdapter.ViewHolder.onCreateViewHolder");
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_premises, parent, false), onItemClickListener);
    }

    //Required method that binds the data to the viewholder.
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PremiseAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Get current premise.

        // Populate the textviews with data.
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("rcvTest", "PremiseAdapter.getItemCount");
        return mPremiseData.size();
    }


    /*----------------------------------- CLASS VIEWHOLDER -------------------------------------------*/
    /*----------------------------------- CLASS VIEWHOLDER -------------------------------------------*/

    /*class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {*/
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // Member Variables for the TextViews

        //Constructor for the ViewHolder, used in onCreateViewHolder().
        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_premise);

            Log.d("rcvTest", "[ViewHolder].ViewHolder.TOP");
            // Initialize the views.

            // Set the OnClickListener to the entire view.
            int clickedColor = Color.parseColor("#D5F5E3");

            itemView.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                Log.d("rcvTest", "[ViewHolder].ViewHolder.listener: " + listener);
                Log.d("rcvTest", "[ViewHolder].ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition(): " + getAdapterPosition());
                Log.d("rcvTest", "[ViewHolder].ViewHolder.position: " + position);
                Log.d("rcvTest", "getLayoutPosition(): " + getLayoutPosition());

                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    Log.d("rcvTest", "[ViewHolder].ViewHolder.position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION");
                    itemView.setBackgroundColor(clickedColor);
                } else if (position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    Log.d("rcvTest", "[ViewHolder].ViewHolder.position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION");
                    itemView.setBackgroundColor(clickedColor);
                }
                notifyItemChanged(position);
                notifyItemChanged(getLayoutPosition());
            });
        }

        void bindTo(Premise currentPremise) {
            // Populate the textviews with data.
            Log.d("rcvTest", "[ViewHolder].bindTo.TOP: " + currentPremise.getPremiseName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. Recently I have code this and its working fine, hope so it will solve your problem too.

```
 int row_index = -1;
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            row_index = position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        });
        if (row_index == position) {
            holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff6600"));
        } else {
            holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
```

Comment: thank you for answering. May I know where should I implement this? The similar code that I have is stored in `ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemClickListener listener)` in the `ViewHolder` class but I dont have a `holder` in it.

Comment: Thanks Price Ali for explaining the code for him. sorry for late reply Ali explained right to you.

Comment: @AtresJuni  row_index is globe variable and add the remaining code in onBindViewHolder.  (holder.layout) is the root layout where you want to add the background color.

Comment: this works! I changed `notifyDataSetChanged();` to `notifyItemChanged(position);` so that the color stays the same when I click another item. But why is that though?

Comment: good to know. So you can accept the answer now.

Comment: ok sure thing! but before that, can you explain why `notifyDataSetChanged()` produce different outcome from `notifyItemChanged(position)` @ahmadbajwa

Comment: As notifyDataSetChanged() notify the whole data set and notifyItemChanged(position) only notify the given item. Its just like refreshing one index and the whole list.

Comment: If you are simply updating one part of the view, use the notifyItemRangeChanged()or notifyItemChanged() instead of notifiyDataSetChanged(). The difference here has to do with structural changes vs item changes.

Comment: @AtresJuni ok thanks but still you did not accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I usually implement onclick listeners in onbindviewholder and they seem to work fine. I would suggest that you should try that.
Move this piece of code to onbindviewholder

```
           int clickedColor = Color.parseColor("#D5F5E3");
            /*itemView.setBackgroundColor(defaultColor);*/

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                Log.d("rcvTest", "[ViewHolder].ViewHolder.listener: " + listener);
                Log.d("rcvTest", "[ViewHolder].ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition(): " + getAdapterPosition());
                Log.d("rcvTest", "[ViewHolder].ViewHolder.position: " + position);
                Log.d("rcvTest", "getLayoutPosition(): " + getLayoutPosition());

                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    Log.d("rcvTest", "[ViewHolder].ViewHolder.position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION");
                    /*listener.onItemClick(position);*/
                    itemView.setBackgroundColor(clickedColor);
                } else if (position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    Log.d("rcvTest", "[ViewHolder].ViewHolder.position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION");

                    itemView.setBackgroundColor(clickedColor);
                }
                notifyItemChanged(position);
                position = getLayoutPosition();
                notifyItemChanged(position); //duplicate
            });
```

Just make sure to change

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(...)   to   holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(...)
```

Comment: Change it to ```holder.itemView``` to be specific.

Comment: @PrinceAli yeah sure